# Why my php header() is not working?

Tags: php

My simple header() function not working.

login.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container ">
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-form">
        <h2 align="center" style="padding-top: 10px;">Log In</h2>
        <form action="logincheck.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label1">UserName</label>
            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label2">Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="********">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="LOG IN">
        <?php /*
            if($errormsg != ""){
                    echo '<label class="label3 alert alert-danger">'.$errormsg.'</label>';
            } */
        ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And my logincheck.php is

```
<?php 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    header("location : login.php");
?>
```

And I got " The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. "

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: header("Location : login.php"); capital L

Comment: changing to capital L don't work. I've tried that.

Answer (score 0):

**Case sensitivity issue**

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `logincheck.php` file header should be like

```
header("Location : login.php");
```